# Exception handling

Tags: c#, .net, exception

When handling exceptions for example in a method in my presentation logic, is it ok to catch all possible exceptions in a one catch block as follows if the only purpose here is alerting the user.

```
void Do()
{
    try
    {
        // ...
    }    
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.message);
    }
}
```

Or else should we always catch every possible exceptions (like `OutOfMemoryException`, `NullReferenceException` etc. followed by more generalized exceptions) in separate catch blocks?

Since the information in `e.message` is not relevant for average users, we could do like:

```
MessageBox.Show("Exception occurred and contact system administrator");
```

Is that the standard way? Then how an administrator trace the error (as stack trace is not showing)?

NOTE: My sole purpose is to alert user and try to keep the system up (without crashing).

Comment: It depends on your needs. If you want to do some special action, or send special message to Logger or to user for some type of exception, you should use more catch blocks. But if it doesn't matter and in each catch block you would have the same code, use only Exception

Comment: If the message depends on the logger for ex. for admin we should show stack trace information, do you handle it using If, Else ?

Comment: maybe If, Else or send exception to some appropriate class that resolves what to show

Answer (score 7):

Thats a very bad practice. If you need to catch an exception then catch the specialized one and then react to it. You basically only catch exceptions that you can handle and not all that could occur. 
And good code design can also help to prevent exceptions from being thrown at you. For example you can use the Null Object pattern to omit or significantly reduce the risk of a`NullReferenceException` to be thrown. The Try/Do pattern is also doing well to avoid NullReference exceptions.

Please read [MSDN - Exception Handling.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229005%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

An error message displayed to the user should also be more specific and offer some detail but without being too technical (e.g. instead of 'MemoryWriteException occurred' you would display 'Insufficient space on disk. Please free up...'. 
An exception that was handled in code doesn't need to be propagated to the user. This spoils the application flow and overall experience for there is nothing the user could do about it. Consider using a logger instead that can be accessed by the developers.

See [MSDN - Error Message Guidlines.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

It's good to use the general Exception in your code. It's the most common way to use it. There is not an standard, but best practices. A kind of rules for using specific exception could be:

1. Manage resources (files, connections, third party components, etc.)
2. Throw your own exceptions when a business rule is broken (create your own exception classes for that)
3. Processes you think can throw other kind of exceptions (threads,asynchronous, call to services, etc).
4. Add exception types in order to improve the code and manage flow.

In general the more complex your code is, the more try catch and exception types you have to use.
Anyway, Exceptions aren't a UI tool but a development resource.